# Linode (or any other VPS really): Choosing a hosting package for a Django webapp

Tags: linux, hosting, web-hosting, vps, resources

I have a Django app that is regionally focused on NYC and am looking at hosting solutions.

I see [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) has a Newark location; going with the assumption I could chose the location.

There's a few articles comparing VPS solutions. My questions is:

1. How do I go about choosing a package once I decided the solution?
2. When do I know it's time for an upgrade? (Any specific metrics would be appreciated)
3. What kind of things should I do to ease the transition to an upgrade if I find it to be necessary? I already use [virtualenv](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2010/01/17/django-virtualenv-pip-and-fabric/) to package the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend linode.

1. It really depends on your app that your building and how much traffic you expect. I would start out at the smallest package and work your way up.
2. There are a few ways. Linode's dashboard will show you the CPU usage, but you should find a way to monitor the whole server (I recommend Server Density). This is an opinion but I would upgrade if you start using 75% of your memory or CPU usage. Memory is usually the limiting factor.
3. A version control system and an well planned way to deploy the app. If you have a good plan to deploy your app then you can deploy it to any server at anytime. BUT since you are using linode the upgrade is painless. If there is a VPS in the size you want available then you upgrade it and all your data will be copied over. I have experienced about 5 min of downtime from this.

HTH

When you buy a linode try to use [this link](http://www.linode.com/?r=707540da8e4c0236bac67ce2fb77df3a96b57778) (referal link)